# IE6/7 literally interpret whitespace in list items

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-lists

How do you get Internet Explorer 6 and 7 to not literally interpret whitespace and line breaks in HTML list items? In the image below, I have marked the undesired whitespace in red. I would prefer to not squeeze everything into one giant line of code. It's very hard to read that way. Is there a CSS alternative?

[image: http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/8583/listdu.png]

```
<ol>
 <li>
  <img>
  Sentence 1
  Sentence 2
 </li>
 <li>
  <img>
  sentence
 </li>
 <li>
  sentence
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please include the full CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some useful information [Closing gaps in ie](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/)

Comment: This screwed up my site. I have many display:none spans containing other language translations. The act of adding display:inline-block made all 20 languages appear at once.

Comment: Add an id to the ol <ol id="myid">... and change the styles to start with #myid. You generally don't want to apply changes like this to ALL elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different browser? haha, but in all seriousness, i would suggest just formatting your code to show it properly. Perhaps encapsulating the sentances in spans could do it

```
<ol>
 <li>
  <img>
  <span>Sentence 1</span>
  <span>Sentence 2</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <img>
  <span>sentence</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span>sentence</span>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How would wrapping text in spans have any effect on the page rendering?

Comment: its IE, why would whitespace do that in the first place..., it could ignore the whitespace infront because of the span tags now. Im not sure, i havent tried it

Comment: could we get the css that you are using too?

Comment: Please try things before suggesting them.

Comment: look around at a lot the answers given on SO.... and dont revive something over two years old